# regex split to implement tokenizer

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a string with all possible chars and now I want to split it by following 
"+"
",OU="

can anyone show me how to do this with regex.split?
I tried many times, but still no luck
I'm using C#

Comment: What do you mean by, 'split it by following "+", ",OU="'? Do you mean that you want both `+` and `,OU=` to act as delimiters?

Comment: YES, that's what i meant, im actually looking for tokenizer for c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `string.split`, which you can specify multiple separators.

`string[] separator = new string[]{"+", ",OU="};`

`string[] resultTokens = testString.split(separator, StringSplitOption.None);`

Answer (score 2):

for the Regex version :

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(yourstring, @"\+|OU=");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have needed a backslash in front of the "+" to treat it as a literal, and you're probably defining the regex using a string, so the string itself will want the backslash character escaped.  It can be easier to read to use square brackets instead.

```
"([+]|,[Oo][Uu]=)"
```

Comment: first, thank you for the help, the result still shows "+" and ",OU=", How do we make it not show?

Comment: Sure... it might help to see the code you're trying.  The Regex.Split command returns a string array.  Is that where you're looking for your results?